# "不管我做什么，她都说我能做得更好。" What is the function of "都" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, ambiguity

"不管我做什么，她都说我能做得更好。" What is the function of "都" in this sentence?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: My view is that since her critical comment is  "她都说我能做得更好", the first part should be "不管我做得多好"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

都 has many functions:

(1) [adv] all, both, without exception;

(2) [adv] even, already;

In this context, 都 means "without exception"

> 不管我做什么，她(**都**)说我能做得更好 - no matter what I do, she, (**without exception**), says I can do better

*Try to fill in the different meanings of 都 in the bracket, you would find "without exception" is the most suitable one*

Note:

Other answers suggested "always". Since "without exception" implies "always", and "always" in other words is "without exception", all the answers so far are valid.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about my gf! (a perfectionist with OCD! (Don't tell her I said that!))

I would translate 都 here as 'always'

不管我做什么，
Doesn't matter what I do,

她都说我能做得更好。
she always says I could do it better.

不管我做什么，
Whatever I do,

她都说她可以做得更好。
she always says she could do it better.

Answer (score 2):

不管我做什么，她都说我能做得更好。 - No matter what I do, she always says I can do better.

always = 总是；一直；始终；永远；随时；无论如何.

都 = all; entirely; both (if two things are involved).

From this sentence, we can see "she" was been critical to him, or trying to encourage him. Either way, "always" is a better fit.

Do not confuse with the sentence,

不管我做什么，她都说: "我能做得更好"。 = No matter what I do, she always says she can do better.

Punctuation can change the meaning of a sentence in a significant way.